# Ubuntu 16.04 black screen on boot

Tags: boot, nvidia, graphics

I have just installed **Ubuntu 16.04** on my laptop, a Dell Inspiron 3543 (Intel i5 at 2.2 Ghz, 4GB ram, nvidia 820m) and every time i boot it, i get a black screen. I did not install any proprietary drivers for the graphic card, because none were available when i looked for them. Here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Thank you in advance! Since i am new to Ubuntu, I would really appreciate if you could give me detailed steps.

P.S. I managed to take those screenshots by connecting the laptop to an external monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing the nvidia drivers through the terminal?

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install nvidia-364

Comment: Thank you! Although it didn't solve the black screen problem, the nvidia graphic card is now recognised by Ubuntu